Difference b/w JWT and the access token using gcloud gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file and gcloud auth print-access-token
I don't have any idea about JWT and access token. currently I am using access token by generating thought the command line. after that I have moved that to 12 hours lifetime. now the picture is I want to generate same thing using node js. Can anyone know it will help me a lot?


JWT- Used for secure information exchange and authentication.       It’s    perfect for stateless authentication in web applications, so     it is    widely used for authentication and authorization purposes.

OAuth: Is great for authorization and delegating access,          especially when    dealing with third-party applications, that is        temporary access to    the API’s.


gcloud auth activate-service-account Authorize access to Google Cloud with a service account. OAuth 2.0 access token is useful for authenticating access from a service account to Google Cloud APIs. OAuth is great for authorization and delegating access, especially when dealing with third-party applications.
gcloud auth print-access-token Displays the current service account's access token and prints an access token for the specified account.
Refer to this Digitalocean community and Go To Developer center document to generate access tokens by using node.js.
For create a token generation
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const secretKey = 'your-secret-key';
function generateAccessToken(payload) {
return jwt.sign(payload, secretKey, { expiresIn: '12h' }); 
const token = generateAccessToken({ user: 'abc', role: 'admin' });
console.log(token);

For using token
app.get('/protected', (req, res) => {
    const token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];  //Authorization header using the Bearer schema.
    jwt.verify(token, secretKey, (err, decoded) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(401).send('Invalid token');
        }
        res.send(`Access granted for user: ${decoded.user}`);
    });
});


Refer to this to know more information about the difference between JWT and OAuth

refresh token also I read.. I didn't get that.. much clarity on that.. can you do that one also

OAuth Refresh Token is a credential artifact when the access token expires it can be used to get a new access token without user interaction. Access tokens have limited lifetimes.The application should store the refresh token for future use, once the access token expires, the application uses the refresh token to obtain a new one.If your application needs access to a Google API beyond the lifetime of a single access token, it can obtain it by a refresh token.

In node Js you can use, jsonwebtoken library to generate the access token. You can follow below steps to create the access token.

Install jsonwebtoken library by npm install jsonwebtoken

Define a secret key. (This should be secure and random value which is stored safely)

Define payload data

Set expiration time

Generate the token using jwt.sign() function
Note:
You can follow the below link to get the full code experience about access token and refresh token


